# order SQL result by a specific field data

Tags: php, sql

Using following PHP code I am getting the below given result.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE user='$userid'";

id | address | default
1 | address1 |   no
2 | address2 |   no
3 | address3 |   no
4 | address4 |   yes
5 | address5 |   no
6 | address6 |   no
```

See the default 'yes', I would like to show that first always. there will be only one yes in default field always.

Following is the desired result.

```
id | address | default
--------------------
 4 | address4 |   yes
 1 | address1 |   no
 2 | address2 |   no
 3 | address3 |   no
 5 | address5 |   no
 6 | address6 |   no
```

I tried the following, but it shows error.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE user='$userid' ORDER BY FIELD(default,'yes')";`

error
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''yes')' at line 1

Fix: Thanks to @Jens, as he suggeted ("default is a keyword. rename the column or enclose it with backticks") I renamed the default column into defaultaddress and it worked.

Comment: `default` is a keyword. rename the column or enclose it with backticks

Comment: @Jens, I renamed the column and it worked, thank you.